# Reading XML Value Using Schema XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am having XML tag as below.

My tries to read unitcode value using XSD Script and it's result are,

```
XML Tag: <AllocatedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="EA">4.0</AllocatedBaseUOMQuantity>

Try1: <xsl:value-of select="*:AllocatedBaseUOMQuantity[@unitCode]/text()"/> : Result = 4.0
Try2: <xsl:value-of select="*:OpenBaseUOMQuantity/@unitCode/text()"/> : Resut = ""
Try3: <xsl:value-of select="*:OpenBaseUOMQuantity/unitCode/text()"/> : Resut = ""
```

I want to get unitcode value "EA" as a output. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
MGP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this question is very confused. I don't see any XSD "script" here. Are you confusing XSD with XSLT?

The XPath expression you are looking for is

```
select="*:AllocatedBaseUOMQuantity/@unitCode"
```

Rather than just putting this in your code, I'd suggest you do some reading so that you understand why it works, and why your attempts don't. It looks very much as if you were trying a scatter-gun approach, trying out different constructs without understanding their meaning, and that's never going to be an efficient way of programming.